# Actions class obje

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

This is giving

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Cant I call objects of actions class multiple times?
If I create a new object then it works fine

```
public void  actionMethods() throws Exception 
{
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);      
    WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-37\"]/a"));
    act.moveToElement(ele1).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-4868\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    act.moveToElement(ele1).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-4877\"]/a")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move to different page or even refresh the current page the `driver` "losses" all the elements it previously located.

`ele1` is stale after the page navigation, you need to relocate it before you use it in the second `act.moveToElement(ele1)`.

```
driver.navigate().back();
driver.navigate().refresh();
Thread.sleep(2000);

// find ele1 again
ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-37\"]/a"));
act.moveToElement(ele1).build().perform();
```